# TFS 2013 Web Access - Licence Permissions

Tags: tfs

As you know, in TFS 2013, from a permissions point of view, we have 3 licences available to us:

Stakeholder
Basic
Advanced

As far as I am aware, Advanced is the only way of accessing 'TEST' area (Test Case Management), however, is it possible to create 'custom' security licences as we would like to give access to certain users to the 'TEST' area but not have them access other areas where they can create other WITs or potentially modify open WITs - We just want them to be able to view and run Test Cases + create a BUG where required.

We are using TFS 2013 On Premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot achieve that. We cannot custome the access levels to add/reduce the supported features for each level.

> For TFS 2017 and earlier versions, you should assign the **Advanced**
>   level to those users for whom you've purchased the full Test feature
>   set.

Advanced access level include all Basic features. And TFS doesn't provide a more granular permissions settings. So we cannot restrict the users who in Advanced access level to only view and run Test Cases + create a BUG. That is contradictory. We can only set the user permissions based on the existing options.

Please see [About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/access-levels); [Change access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/change-access-levels) and [Permissions and groups in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions) for more information.